how to update i18n messages on nuxt app with api response, after initialisation
I am working on an application in Nuxt 3, with i18n. I am trying to use an API response to update the messages, after the initialisation.
we have severals app that use the same dictionary, we want to avoid making the same change in multiple places.
The i18n config file is very simple.
import { locales } from '~/locales/locales.js'

export default {
legacy: false,
locale: 
'fr',
locales: ['fr', 'en'],
defaultLocale: 'fr',
fallbackLocale: 'fr',
messages: locales,
}

I have tried several methods: setLocaleMessage, modifying locales in the config, but with no result. Do you know a way to achieve this?
thank you
SOLUTION:
Finally updated the list of messages with $i18n.messages.value
